# How to search for a particular file or all files from a graphical interface

Tags: nautilus, search

Is there some graphical tool to search for a particular file or all files of that format from a folder and many sub-folders and which takes a query like `*.txt` and the path of the partition on which the folder with many sub-folders is located and output the result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open Nautilus, the default file manager, by searching the dash for Files or clicking Files in the Launcher.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>

Type your search. You can chose whether to search in the Current folder or All Files. For just `txt` files, type `txt`. Not the wildcard (although it may work, I don't think it does).

[image: gif animation of above]

Comment: How can I install `nautilus` in Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: @MuditKapil Simply type `sudo apt-get install nautilus` into your terminal. It should be preinstalled on your system, by the way - it's default file browser.

Comment: @Jacajack How can I search for all files of a particular type like `*.txt`

Comment: @MuditKapil Simply type `txt` to search textbox as it's been told before.

Comment: @MuditKapil I explained both of these in the answer - Nautilus is the default file browser, and to search for `txt` files just type `txt`. Next time read the answer properly before commenting please...

Comment: @MuditKapil No, that edit wasn't what I meant. I'm saying to open nautilus (Files) by searching the dash or the launcher then press Ctrl+F then type the query, *in nautilus (Files)*. Are you still confused what I'm suggesting?

Comment: @Tim OK thanks for the answer basically to press Ctrl+F after clicking Files :)

Comment: @MuditKapil Yes :) I'm adding a screen recording now.